# How to disable DropDownList option in asp.net at server-side?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist to fill in server-side an some of the options that will filled to the this list need to be disabled. Practically I know that I need to add a disabled='disabled' attribute.

That is the first way I tried.

```
Dim avListItems = activityVersions.Select(Function(av) New With {.Text = av.Text, .Value = av.Value, .Disabled=av.HasQuota}).ToList()
```

But this disables all options because in HTML disabled attribute do not need a value if there is a disabled attribute then it disables the option in any case. But I need a solution which could add disabled attribute for the options, which has no quota and other should be enabled.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Show please the code where you insert this data into the DDL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not possible to disable individual items in a dropdown list. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.enabled.aspx).

Perhaps rather apply some validation to notify the user if an invalid option has been selected, or remove those items from the list entirely.

Comment: Your right its not allowed via the asp.net control, but it is allowed in HTML so you can just over ride it after the bind event, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

It is in fact possible to disable an item in the drop-down list. what you need to do is bind the list then add a new attribute to it. 
The example below assumes a list of countries..

```
List<Country> countryList = CountryFunctions.CreateCountryCollection();

                ddlCountryList.DataSource = countryList;
                ddlCountryList.DataTextField = "Name";
                ddlCountryList.DataValueField = "Code";
                ddlCountryList.DataBind();

                //Disable any preselected items in dropdown list
                foreach (var country in countryList)
                {
                    var disabledCountry = IsCountryDisabled(country.Code);

                    if (country.Id != 0)
                    {
                        ddlCountryList.Items.FindByValue(country.Code).Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
                    }
                }
```